# Using Windows 8.1 and VBScript I need to create a folder in APPDATA. this is my code and I'm getting the error Path Not Found

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I'm trying to create a folder in \username\appdata\local\ using Widows8.1 but the code I have is giving error path not found. please help!

```
Option Explicit

Dim oShell, oEnv, oFS, strDirectory, LocalAppData, wshshell

Set oShell = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
set oFS = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oEnv = oShell.Environment("Process")
set wshshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

strDirectory = oEnv("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents\MyConnect"
If Not oFS.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then oFS.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
```

I think My error is here

```
LocalAppData = wshshell.expandenvironmentstrings("%APPDATA%") &           "\Local\MyConnectSettings"
If Not oFS.FolderExists (LocalAppData)  Then oFS.CreateFolder (LocalAppData)
```

Answer (score 0):

.CreateFolder won't create intermediate directories (other than mkdir). So make sure `%appdata%\local` exists.

Comment: okay yeah it works! now, how will it be if I want to create it in username\appdata\local? by default %appdata% go to %appdata%\Roaming